# How to use tikzpicture with tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to place my graphs into the same figure vertically. However, I couldn't use `tabular` with `tikzpicture` to do it.

```
\begin{figure}[]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2.csv};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2.csv};
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Something}
    \label{figure_2_s}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C4.csv};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C4.csv};
        \addplot[smooth,color=gray,mark=o,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C4.csv};
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Something}
    \label{figure_4_s}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean 'vertically' and not 'horizontally'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question, but I understand that you want two `tikzpictures` inside a `figure` and probably each one with its label and caption. You can use `subcaption` package. As you want your figures vertically aligned, there's no need for `minipage` or `subfigure` environments, but you must include each figure in its own scope `{...}` if you want distinguish `subcations` from main figure `caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
{%First subfigure
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
%        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick] 
%        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2.csv};
%        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick] 
%        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2.csv};
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{First subfigure}
    \label{figure_2_s}
}

{%Second subfigure    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Second subfigure}
\label{figure_4_s}
}    
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `figure` environments. And you don't need `tabular` too. Put both the `tikzpicture`s inside the same `figure` environment with a blank line between them to make them vertically align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick]
         {rnd};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick]
        {rnd};
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Something}
    \label{figure_2_s}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Performance gain/drop percentage,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
          legend style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
          xticklabels={,,},
          xlabel=Something
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick]
        {rnd};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick]
        {rnd};
        \addplot[smooth,color=gray,mark=o,thick]
        {rnd};
        \legend{Something}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Something}
    \label{figure_4_s}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]